# How to test Facebook Deep Link in Android App through facebook Ad preview (or) through realtime facebook ads

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I am trying to test the facebook deep link using the Ad hosted in FB Ads-Manager (https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager).

I have deep link code in place in my Android App which receives the deep link and prints it for me. When I use "Deep Link Tester" in FB Developer Tools, it sends a notification to my facebook profile and when I click on it, it takes me to my Android App (which is still in development phase/locally installed), my app can read the embedded deep link and print it for me in the expected format (appname://module/1). But in a similar way, if I use FB Ads-Manager to see the Ad-Preview and click on "View on mobile", I get below notification as expected

**Mobile Ad Preview
A notification has been sent to the Facebook account for xyz. Please open Facebook on your phone to preview your ad.**

when I click on this Ad preview from my fb profile notification, it takes me to my local Android App as expected but my App prints only App ID  (like fb123456://) but not the full Deep Link URL which I set on Ad (fb123456://module/1).

Could someone suggest how should I ensure the deep link is working perfectly before my App goes LIVE. Also suggest me why the Ad-Preview deep link URL is not coming fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known to be non-functional (see [here](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/support/ios/#demopreview-ads-do-not-deep-link) for more info). The way you are currently doing it is the least bad approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! you saved my time. In the past, I've checked with Facebook support team, but they were not clear about this Ad-preview functionality.

Comment: This link is broken now

Comment: when deferred deep link is sent via Ads app helper it works but facebook ad preview or even the live ad does give the deep link ...i'm using flutter and stuck with this issue